# Word Referring to a Space that Is Larger on the Inside than Allowed by the Outside

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm almost certain that there is a word for this kind of paradoxical space. But no matter how I phrase the question and enter it into search engines, most results that come up are related to *Doctor Who*, and those that aren't still don't help.
Does anyone know it is?

Comment: The concept is first introduced to most people in the form of *Doctor Who* so it's understandable that it is everywhere.

Comment: Um yeah. TARDIS.  See also bag of holding and portable hole.

Comment: This seems like a terminology question on Mathematics topology.

Comment: I immediately think of Harry Potter concepts like the Weasleys’ Ford Anglia and Hermione’s string bag, but that’s just me…

Comment: I think that if you want to avoid saying "Tardis-like" or similar then "impossibly large" is the best you'll do.

Comment: "Tardis-like" would be the best-understood term.

Comment: @HotLicks Depending on your intended target group. If you’d used that word with me about five years ago, I wouldn’t have had the faintest idea what you were talking about, and in most of the non-Anglosphere, I suspect the majority of people still won’t. _Doctor Who_ is ubiquitous in some places, obscure in others.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Actually, *Doctor Who* was far more ubiquitous five-ten years ago.

Comment: A 'black hole' seems to non-generically qualify: https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.2854

Comment: @HotLicks' *tardis-like* appears in the OED with this definition. While absence of evidence isn't necessarily evidence of absence, I do think it's probably significant that that definition doesn't include any synonyms. I wouldn't expect any word for this sci-fi-ish concept to be exactly mainstream, and I *would* expect virtually all theoretical physicist-types to be at least aware of Dr Who, so this seems like a perfectly adequate term. For any non-technical purpose, phrases like *surprisingly spacious* presumably suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a proper word, but **hammerspace** is used to describe this phenomenon.

> *Hammerspace* (also known as malletspace) is a fan-envisioned extradimensional, instantly accessible storage area in fiction, which is used to explain how animated, comic, and game characters can produce objects out of thin air.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammerspace)

It's often used more for the concept of a person having access to this, but the concept would carry to something like the TARDIS.